# Laws of Exponents

Tags: linear-algebra

If $xyz=1$, then prove that 
$$(1+x+y^{-1})^{-1}+ (1+y+z^{-1})^{-1} + (1+z+x^{-1})^{-1}=1.$$

I have tried to solve it, but the calculation does not stand fit. Please help me solve this.

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

HINT : $$\begin{align}\frac{1}{1+x+\frac 1y}+\frac{1}{1+y+\frac 1z}+\frac{1}{1+z+\frac 1x}&=\frac{y}{y+xy+1}+\frac{1}{1+y+xy}+\frac{xy}{xy+xyz+y}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, think about the negative exponents being on the bottom of the fraction and if a negative exponent is to the power of a negative exponent it will then be moved to the top of the fraction